# 2 routers in different module for the same mage controller

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout, controllers, router

I have a question.

I would like to rewrite a method of the controller Mage_Checkout_OnepageController.

The method is: saveBillingAction

But I found in other module already a router on this controller. It rewrites the other method.

So i have  :

```
class Mage_Checkout_OnepageController extends Mage_Checkout_Controller_Action
{
...
  /**
     * save checkout billing address
     */
    public function saveBillingAction()
    {
     ...
    }
     protected function _getShippingMethodsHtml()
    {
     ...
    }
}
```

AN other module :

```
class Gfi_TNT_Checkout_OnepageController extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController
{
    protected function _getShippingMethodsHtml()
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

And I want to crete in my own module :

```
class Upecom_Checkout_OnepageController extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController
{
    /**
     * save checkout billing address
     */
    public function saveBillingAction()
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do that?
I tried with :

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Upecom_Checkout before="Mage_Checkout">Upecom_Checkout</Upecom_Checkout>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

But it doesn't work sadly :(
And I can't modify the gfi tnt controller

Do you have a solution for that?

Cheers

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

In such case, you can override the controller which overrides the checkout controller.

> controller file

```
class Upecom_Checkout_OnepageController extends Gfi_TNT_Checkout_OnepageController
{
    /**
     * save checkout billing address
     */
    public function saveBillingAction()
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

> config.xml

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Upecom_Checkout before="Gfi TNT Router name">Upecom_Checkout</Upecom_Checkout>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```